# Comparing two files: Single column in FirstFile - Multiple columns in SecondFile

Tags: powershell, csv

I've figured out how to compare single columns in two files, but I cant figure out how to compare two files, with one column in the first and multiple columns in the second file. Both containing emails.

**First file.csv** (contains single column with emails)
john@email.com
jack@email.com
jill@email.com

**Second file.csv** (contains multiple column with emails)
john@email.nl,john@email.eu,john@email.com
jill@email.se,jill@email.com,jill@email.us

By comparing I would like to output, the difference. This would result in.

**Output.csv**
jack@email.com

Anyone able to help me? :)

**Single columns comparison and output difference**

```
#Line extracts emails from list
$SubscribedMails = import-csv .\subscribed.csv | Select-Object -Property email

#Line extracts emails from list
$ValidEmails = import-csv .\users-emails.csv | Select-Object -Property email

$compare = Compare-Object $SubscribedMails $ValidEmails -property email -IncludeEqual |  where-object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Export-csv .\nonvalid-emails.csv –NoTypeInformation
(Get-Content .\nonvalid-emails.csv) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ',"<="' } > .\nonvalid-emails.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the first file already contains email addresses per column, you can import it right away.
Take the second file and split the strings containing several addresses.
A new array with seperate addresses will be generated.

Judging from your output, you only seek addresses that are within the first csv but not in the second.

Your code could look like this:

```
$firstFile = Get-Content 'FirstFile.csv'
$secondFile = (Get-Content 'SecondFile.csv').Split(',')

foreach ($item in $firstFile) {
    if ($item -notin $secondFile) {
        $item | Export-Csv output.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$One = (Get-Content .\FirstFile.csv).Split(',')

$Two = (Get-Content .\SecondFile.csv).Split(',')

$CsvPath = '.\Output.csv'

$Diff = @() 

(Compare-Object ($One | Sort-Object) ($two | Sort-Object)| `
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}).inputobject | `
    ForEach-Object {$Diff += New-Object PSObject -Property @{email=$_}}

$Diff | Export-Csv -Path $CsvPath -NoTypeInformation
```

`Output.csv` will contain entries that exist in FirstFile but not SecondFIle.

Comment: Output does not contain entries. It outputs:

`#TYPE System.String<br>
Length<br>
18<br>
18<br>
19<br>
`

Comment: @Hogne I've updated my answer, could you please review and let me know? Also in your question you say that you'd like to output the difference, but given your example, it seems you would like to output items that appear in First but not Second.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your code, can you consider a script like:

```
    #Line extracts emails from list
    $SubscribedMails = import-csv .\subscribed.csv | Select-Object -Property email

    Rename-Item .\users-emails.csv users-emails.csv.bk
    Get-Content .\users-emails.csv.bk).replace(',', "`r`n") | Set-Content .\users-emails.csv

    #Line extracts emails from list
    $ValidEmails = import-csv .\users-emails.csv | Select-Object -Property email


    $compare = Compare-Object $SubscribedMails $ValidEmails -property email -IncludeEqual |  where-object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Export-csv .\nonvalid-emails.csv –NoTypeInformation
    (Get-Content .\nonvalid-emails.csv) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ',"<="' } > .\nonvalid-emails.csv

    Remove-Item .\users-emails.csv
    Rename-Item .\users-emails.csv.bk users-emails.csv
```

or, more simplest

```
    #Line extracts emails from list
    $SubscribedMails = import-csv .\subscribed.csv | Select-Object -Property email

    Get-Content .\users-emails.csv).replace(',', "`r`n") | Set-Content .\users-emails.csv.bk

    #Line extracts emails from list
    $ValidEmails = import-csv .\users-emails.csv.bk | Select-Object -Property email


    $compare = Compare-Object $SubscribedMails $ValidEmails -property email -IncludeEqual |  where-object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | Export-csv .\nonvalid-emails.csv –NoTypeInformation
    (Get-Content .\nonvalid-emails.csv) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ',"<="' } > .\nonvalid-emails.csv

    Remove-Item .\users-emails.csv.bk
```

Comment: As I understand these codes, `-Property email` defines the column which is supposed to be used when comparing. And here a single column `-Property email` it the first file is compared with a single column `-Property email` in the second file (not multiple columns, as wanted)

Answer (score 0):

**None of the suggestions so far works :( 

Still hoping :)

Will delete comment when happy :p**